# Why is $1-P(A)P(B)$ not equal to $P(A')P(B')$

Tags: probability

$P(Z \le 10) = P(X \le 10)P(Y \le 10)$

Say it's easier to calculate $P(X \gt 10)$ and $P(Y \gt 10)$.

Why is $P(Z \le 10) = 1 - P(X \gt 10)P(Y \gt 10)$

and not

$P(Z \le 10) = (1 - P(X\gt10))(1 - P(Y \gt 10))$

Comment: Please, use MathJax

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know $$\LaTeX$$ off by heart!

Comment: Your phrasing feels off... "*Why is $P(Z\leq 10) = 1 - P(X>10)P(Y>10)$ and not...*"  The way you phrased this sounds like you think that this equation should have been the true one.  Meanwhile your title makes it sound like you think this equation is the false one.  To be perfectly clear, this equation is false in most circumstances.

Comment: If you move things to one side, you would have had $P(A)P(B)+P(A')P(B')=1$.  In the case that $A$ and $B$ are independent events, what would have been true is $Pr(A)Pr(B)+\color{red}{Pr(A')Pr(B)+Pr(A)Pr(B')}+Pr(A')Pr(B')=1$.  You fell into the trap of thinking "Not [A and B]" is equivalent to "[Not A] and [Not B]," something well known to be incorrect.

Comment: @JMoravitz >> You fell into the trap of thinking "Not [A and B]" is equivalent to "[Not A] and [Not B]," something well known to be incorrect. <<

An explanation of this is what I am fishing for!

Comment: Oh. De Morgan's law explains. not (a and b) = (not a) or (not b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}P(A')P(B') &=& (1-P(A))(1-P(B))\\ &=& 1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A)P(B)\end{eqnarray}

So this would be true only if $$P(A)+P(B)=2P(A)P(B)$$